# JSONP - Using to access data website in conjuction with leaflet

Tags: leaflet, jsonp

I am having trouble getting jsonp to work for a data serving website.  Below is my script that will plot data points on a leaflet map as long as they are in the same domain.  I need to take it a step further by using jsonp.  I am having trouble understanding jsonp tutorials, especially with understanding how to deal with the response of the json file.  This is my first time trying to use this method, and I have not be successful as I still don't fully understand js/html that well. Any help would be great as I think I am just a few lines of code from being able to get this to work properly. Thanks.

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>A Leaflet map!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css"/>
  <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    #map{ width: 1000px; height: 600px; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="map"></div>

  <script>

  var map = L.map('map',{center: [35, -121],zoom: 7});
  var myStyle = {"color": "#ff7800", "weight": 5, "opacity": 0.65};

  L.tileLayer('http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Ocean_Basemap/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {attribution: 'Tiles © Esri — Sources: GEBCO, NOAA, CHS, OSU, UNH, CSUMB, National Geographic, DeLorme, NAVTEQ, and Esri'}).addTo(map);

  $.getJSON("http://localhost:8000/erdCalCOFIcufes.geojson", function(data) {
      L.geoJson(data, {
        style: myStyle
      }).addTo(map);
  })

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that it is hosted locally as detailed below.  The website I need to use is here...

https://coastwatch.pfeg.noaa.gov/erddap/tabledap/erdCalCOFIcufes.geoJson?longitude,latitude,sardine_eggs&cruise=%22201504%22&sardine_eggs%3E=0&.draw=markers&.marker=5%7C5&.color=0x000000&.colorBar=%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C&.bgColor=0xffccccff

Here is what is looks like without a proper jsonp to grab data to plot.  Currently, I have been able to grab the data by hosting the scripts in the same domain as the geojson file using the following...

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

This was more for proof of concept and wont fit my needs.

```html
    <html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>A Leaflet map!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css"/>
  <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    #map{ width: 1000px; height: 600px; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="map"></div>

  <script>

  var map = L.map('map',{center: [35, -121],zoom: 7});
  var myStyle = {"color": "#ff7800", "weight": 5, "opacity": 0.65};
  
  L.tileLayer('http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Ocean_Basemap/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {attribution: 'Tiles © Esri — Sources: GEBCO, NOAA, CHS, OSU, UNH, CSUMB, National Geographic, DeLorme, NAVTEQ, and Esri'}).addTo(map);

  $.getJSON("http://localhost:8000/erdCalCOFIcufes.geojson", function(data) {
      L.geoJson(data, {
        style: myStyle
      }).addTo(map);
  })

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The geojson file looks like the following.  I cut out a lot of points to make it more digestible.

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "propertyNames": ["sardine_eggs"],
  "propertyUnits": ["count"],
  "features": [

{"type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [-123.3226, 38.1476] },
  "properties": {
    "sardine_eggs": 0 }
},
{"type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [-123.3527, 38.1785] },
  "properties": {
    "sardine_eggs": 1 }
},
{"type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [-123.369, 38.238] },
  "properties": {
    "sardine_eggs": 0 }
},
{"type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [-117.3725, 32.6873] },
  "properties": {
    "sardine_eggs": 0 }
},
{"type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [-117.2973, 32.6538] },
  "properties": {
    "sardine_eggs": 0 }
}

  ],
  "bbox": [-126.5296, 29.8483, -117.2931, 43.7501]
}
```